# How to correctly build a training/validation/test?

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation

I have a database  that is comprised of 3 sets of data. The first created in office conditions, the second in the same office taken on different day and the third drawn from random images from the internet.

On one hand I could mix them all up and randomly draw the samples for the training/validation/test sets. Or should I use for example one set from the office for training, the second set from the office as the validation and the third set of images from the web as the test?

Which option is better at testing my classifier?